# Database availability during database update

Tags: sql-server, database, data-migration, sql-update

I have a database from a 3rd party.  They supply a tool to update the database data weekly.  The tool is pretty old and uses ODBC.  Updates can either be incremental or can delete all database data then recreate the data.  The update can take several hours.   In order to have high availability,  it was suggested to have 2 SQL databases, and store a "active database" setting in another database to determine which of the two databases applications should use (while the other could be being updated).

One issue we are running into is:  How to do reference the active database in stored procedures in other databases?

Is this the right approach?   Is there a simple, perhaps-infrastructure-based approach?  (Should this be posted on ServerFault?)

Note:  Databases are read-only besides the update tool.

Answer (score 1):

If the databases are on different servers, you can create an alias for the server which will redirect to the other server in SQL Server Configuration Manager.  Under SQLNative Client 10.0 Configuration (or 9.0 if you're in SQL Server 2005) you can add a new alias.

Otherwise, you can always rename the databases using sp_dbrename so thata your client applications are always using database1 while you are updating database2.

Comment: If only you could make a alias for a database ... and switch it programmatically.   
What happens when you execute sp_dbrename when users are reading from the database?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use different databases inside a stored procedure you either need to:

1. Duplicate all the calls. Ugly. You would end with a lot of:

   ```
   if @firstDatabase=1
     select * from database1..ExampleTable where ...
   else
     select * from database2..ExampleTable where ...
   ```
2. Use dynamic queries. Less ugly:

   ```
   set @sqlQuery='select * from '+@currentDatabase+'..ExampleTable where...'
   exec sp_executesql @sqlQuery
   ```

I admit that neither solution is perfect...

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the approach of having the stored procedures in both databases with some sort of automatic trigger to update the stored procedures in the other database if a stored procedure is changed.